# Send a push notification with Firebase Console with custom priority

Tags: firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using recurring FCM notifications in the Firebase console.
I've seen an old Firebase FCM screen allowing you to choose the priority in the console, but it seems that this no longer exists, how do I set the highest priority?

[image: Firebase console screenshot]